# Highlighting text in webview

Tags: iphone

Ha ii everybody,i am doing a bible app ,my requirement is to highlight the verse when the user tap the corresponding verse number eg: if the user tap the verse 1.1 it highlight that verse in yellow or blue color.If the verse no: is gives as link means 1.1 is a link ,the user can tap that link to perform a action by using javascript.I also want a popup menu or alert-view or action[image]-sheet when the user tap the verse no:.I hope you understand my question.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on your UIWebView with script, which change backgroud color of element with the verse.

Comment: It depends how content of UIWebView looks like. For example if your html code looks similar: <p id="verse1.1">Some text</p>, javascript looks: document.getElementById("verse1.1").style.backgroundColor="blue".